# Adding together certain integers in an array

Tags: c++

What I am trying to do in my code is adding together each number with the number directly to the right of it. So Array[0] + Array[1], Array[1] + Array[2], so on. For some reason in my code I get insanely large numbers for the sums and I am not sure why

```
int main()
{

int Array[5];
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   cout<<": Please enter a number."<<endl;
   cin>>Array[5];
}
int n1, n2, n3, n4;

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
cout<<Array[i]<<endl;

n1 = Array[0] + Array[1];
cout<<n1<<endl;

n2 = Array[1] + Array[2];
cout<<n2<<endl;

n3 = Array[2] + Array[3];
cout<<n3<<endl;

 n4 = Array[3] + Array[4];
cout<<n4<<endl;
}
```

Comment: don't you want `cin>>Array[i];` instead of `cin>>Array[5];`

Comment: Yes that fixed it thank you so much!

Comment: Also note that that indexing is `0` based what you tried will yield undefined behaviour as you're indexing off the end of an array so your array would've contained some uninitialised int values which is what you saw outputted

Comment: @FranklinValdez : I see you are new to SO. If an answer satisfies your query, then you are encouraged to accept it by clicking on the green tick next to the answer. This allows users to filter questions which don't have appropriate answers.

Comment: Sorry I usually do but it was giving me a wait time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
cin>>Array[5];
```

to

```
cin>>Array[i];
```

What is currently happening is that your array contains 4 uninitialized values, and the 5th value is overwritten 5 times. The uninitialised values are garbage values, which result in the large sum.

As mentioned in the comments, you should also realise that indexing is 0 based. So `Array[5]` is accessing out of bounds, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: I always get through the toughest parts of a problem but its the simplest things I mess up every time. Thank you so much yes this fixed this. What was happening before when I added it to Array[5]? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @FranklinValdez : Edited it.

Comment: @FranklinValdez When you write to `Array[5]` you write out of bounds of the array, probably overwriting something on the stack. Accessing an array out of bounds, for reading or for writing, leads to *undefined behavior*. Also, since you don't initialize the contents of the array, the values will be *indeterminate* and reading them is *also* undefined behavior.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : Both of us were writing the same thing at the same time :D